# SQL Case Do separate things

Tags: sql, case

I have a trigger that i would like to do separate things depending on certain values. Can you write a case statement to do one thing else do something else Such as below? Is this possible?

```
Case WHEN value1 = 'A' and value2 = 'B' THEN
Insert table 1
WHEN value1 = 'A' and value2 = 'C' THEN
Insert table 2
END
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Triggers are usually product specific.

Comment: Why not if else statements?

Answer (score 0):

Need more explanation what you really want to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use exec. something like this

```
declare @sql nvarchar(1000), @value int
set @value = 1
select @sql = 'select * from ' + CASE @value WHEN 1 then 'tblEvents' ELSE 'tblPerson' END
exec(@sql)
```